# dictionary or a list is suitable data structure for my o/p?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list which are like 1000s of lines of the following o/p and i am storing in a list variable .

Now I want to find the max key and value across all these lines

```
sensors ={'porscheLfsFixit': 0, 'porscheDiskWrite': 1786, 'porscheDiskGcLoad': 0, 'porscheLfsFixit': 0, 'porscheEncrypt': 0, 'porscheDiskGcReap': 0, 'porscheCompress': 0, 'porscheDiskWrite': 1786, 'porscheRaidRebuild': 384, 'porscheCompress': 0, 'porscheDiskGcReap': 0, 'porscheEncrypt': 0, 'porscheRaidRebuild': 384, 'porscheDiskGcLoad': 0}
{'porscheLfsFixit': 0, 'porscheDiskWrite': 1786, 'porscheDiskGcLoad': 0, 'porscheLfsFixit': 0, 'porscheEncrypt': 0, 'porscheDiskGcReap': 0, 'porscheCompress': 0, 'porscheDiskWrite': 1796, 'porscheRaidRebuild': 389, 'porscheCompress': 0, 'porscheDiskGcReap': 50, 'porscheEncrypt': 0, 'porscheRaidRebuild': 3849, 'porscheDiskGcLoad': 0}
```

I try maxValue = max(sensors)

but I am getting only the o/p like this: porscheDiskWrite

I want the max across all the lines like so : porscheDiskWrite': 1796, porscheRaidRebuild': 389  etc ..

Will I need to convert this r\to a dictionary ?

Comment: You have duplicates in your dict, however dict have unique keys, so it would  your `'porscheRaidRebuild'` would be overwritten. Also it's unclear what type of structure `sensors` is.

Comment: If you want to have the max based on the values of your dict, you can do: `max(sensors.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: @ChihebNexus -Thanks , Is there a way to convert the list to a dictionary inorder to do the operation you mentioned ? I am not sure if this output is a list or dictionary, hence the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your source structure is like this, except with more items in each dict:

```
sensors = [{'porscheLfsFixit': 0, 'porscheDiskWrite': 1786, 'porscheRaidRebuild': 384}, {'porscheLfsFixit': 0, 'porscheDiskWrite': 1786, 'porscheRaidRebuild': 9999}]
```

To get the `key, value` pair with highest value of all items of all dicts I suggest this approach.

```
sensor_tuples = []
for sensor in sensors:
    sensor_tuples += list(sensor.items())
max_pair = max(sensor_tuples, key= lambda x: x[1])
```

First you get all pairs into one list:

```
>>> sensor_tuples
[('porscheDiskWrite', 1786), ('porscheRaidRebuild', 384), ('porscheLfsFixit', 0), ('porscheDiskWrite', 1786), ('porscheRaidRebuild', 9999), ('porscheLfsFixit', 0)]
```

Then you just find the max valued pair:

```
>>> max_pair
('porscheRaidRebuild', 9999)
```

EDIT:

Answering the question from comments.
To get **max values for all keys over all dicts** first define a function to get max value over all dicts for one key:

```
def get_max_for_key(alist, key):
    return max(alist, key=lambda x: x[key])[key]
```

Get all keys:

```
keys = sensors[0].keys()
```

Call function for each key and put results in a dict:

```
max_dict = {}
for key in keys:
    max_dict[key] = get_max_for_key(sensors, key)
```

Here we go:

```
>>> max_dict
{'porscheRaidRebuild': 9999, 'porscheLfsFixit': 0, 'porscheDiskWrite': 1786}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer , Can this be extended to get the max values for all possible key values like ('porscheRaidRebuild', 9999), 'porscheDiskWrite': 1786, 'porscheRaidRebuild': 9999 for all possible keys  ?

Comment: @sudeepmathew at this point I suggest you to look at pandas. http://pandas.pydata.org/ . Your structure is very suitable for a grid (DataFrame in pandas) and both of your questions would be solved with single function calls in pandas. If you are going to routinely work with data structured like that then you should really consider pandas.

Comment: @sudeepmathew I will edit the answer to add your second question.

Comment: @sudeepmathew I added the answer. Please note this is a very simple operation. If you don't know how to do it you should try to run my code line by line and simplify it so you understand.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I think this should work , I will try this

Comment: This is my actual execution and the error I am seeing

Comment: >>> max_dict = {}
>>> for key in keys:
...     max_dict[key] = max(sensors, key=lambda x: x[key])[key]
... print(max_dict)
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    print(max_dict)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the max based on the values of your dict, you can do:

```
sensors ={'porscheLfsFixit': 0, 'porscheDiskWrite': 1786, 'porscheDiskGcLoad': 0,  
        'porscheLfsFixit': 0, 'porscheEncrypt': 0, 'porscheDiskGcReap': 0,
        'porscheCompress': 0, 'porscheDiskWrite': 1786, 'porscheRaidRebuild': 384, 
        'porscheCompress': 0, 'porscheDiskGcReap': 0, 'porscheEncrypt': 0,
        'porscheRaidRebuild': 384, 'porscheDiskGcLoad': 0}

my_max = max(sensors.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
print(my_max)
>>> ('porscheDiskWrite', 1786)
```

So, your output in this example is a tuple.

Also, You don't need to convert your dict into a list to use max, and you don't need, too, to convert the output into a list to use it. You can keep it as a tuple and do whatever you want with it.

**PS:** I used a key function with `max()` wich is a `lambda` function that get the element of id = 1 of each element of `sensors.items()`. Also, pay attention that the first element of `max()` must be iterable. And `sensors.items()` will return a list of tuples like `[(key1, value1), ..., (keyN, valueN)]`

Answer (score 0):

***If you want to find all the value different from zero**

```
sensors ={'porscheLfsFixit': 0, 'porscheDiskWrite': 1786, 'porscheDiskGcLoad': 0, 'porscheLfsFixit': 0, 'porscheEncrypt': 0, 'porscheDiskGcReap': 0, 'porscheCompress': 0, 'porscheDiskWrite': 1786, 'porscheRaidRebuild': 384, 'porscheCompress': 0, 'porscheDiskGcReap': 0, 'porscheEncrypt': 0, 'porscheRaidRebuild': 384, 'porscheDiskGcLoad': 0}
>>> val = [(x,y) for x,y in sensors.items() if y>0]
>>> for v in val:
>>>    print(v)
```

output

('porscheRaidRebuild', 384)

('porscheDiskWrite', 1786)

```
>>> dic = {x:y for x,y in sensors.items() if y>0}
>>> dic
```

**To put it into a new dictonary**

output

{'porscheDiskWrite': 1786, 'porscheRaidRebuild': 384}